# Microsoft pixelsense input simulator finger stays pressed

Tags: pixelsense, surface

I have a problem with the Input Simulator in the microsoft surface SDK 2.0.
Whenever I try to simulate a finger or a blob click, the first click stays pressed (like when you put it as placeholder with right click+left click).

I don't know the reason of this behaviour since on other computers it work without problem.
Can it be because of I'm using windows in a virtual machine?  If yes, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by disabling touch pen utilities which was automatically installed with surface SDK.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? Where do I find this touch pen utilities?

Comment: It was an utility installed (or enabled) with the SDK which kept running with an icon in the system tray. Right clicking it gave me the option to disable.